# I am creating an quiz that has a time limit in it. Is there a way the timer is not resetting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem were the timer keeps resetting to a minute when going to other questions is there a way i can keep the time going until it reach the final question ?

here is the code:

```js
<script>
    var seconds = 60;
    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time Out";
                
            alert("You're out of time!");
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        } else {    
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

and

```html
<h4 style="color:#FF0000;position:absolute;left:70%;top:30%;" align="center" >
    <span id="iTimeShow">Time Remaining: </span><br/>
    <span id='countdown' style="font-size:25px;"></span>
</h4>
```

To keep the timer running until the last question or after the timer runs out it will going to the index

Comment: Use cookie to store the start time, and check against the real clock.

Comment: If you are using a pure js timer, then end users can easily hack it with the browser console.